# Can I use IPv6 in Windows 7 if my ISP support it but not my router?

Tags: windows-7, networking, router, ipv6, teredo

I would like to use IPv6 on my desktop computer, it has Windows 7. My ISP has support for IPv6, since if I connects directly to the adsl-modem IPv6 works fine. But my home router doesn't support IPv6 (Netgear WNR2000).

I have heard that Windows 7 has some built in tunneling techniques for IPv6, called [Teredo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teredo_tunneling). Can I use IPv6 in Windows 7 even if my router doesn't support it? How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a difference between an ISP supporting IPv6 and having a full on IPv6 infrastructure.

[Try going to this website](http://ipv6.whatismyv6.com/), if it loads, you are connecting via IPv6, if not, you are not connected. It works by only having an AAAA DNS entry and no standard IPv4 one.

I think that the answer is no / it will not work as the router needs to support it, but you can always try!

Comment: It was [Teredo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teredo_tunneling) I was referencing to.

Answer (score 2):

Teredo dosen't need your ISP to support IPV6 - its a 'tunnel' to a relay server Microsoft and others run. The performance is terrible so you'd be better off taking the effort to set up a tunnel with gogo6 (needs just a simple client for a 'dynamic' ipv6 address, or a simple signup for a fixed one) or hurricane electric.

Answer (score 1):

If your router doesn't support IPV6 then you will not be able to use IPv6 on your home computer as if it connects directly to your router and picks up its DHCP address from there you will not be able to get an IPv6 address.

Comment: It was [Teredo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teredo_tunneling) I was referencing to.

Comment: @jonas - that's the 2nd time I've heard that mentioned today. Might be worth some further reading. Thanks for the update